# Handling authentication token in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

In my current project the application passes an authentication token id after login. So, I have used below.

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]. to extract the token id from Response Data and i applied the token in [image: Http Header Manager].under Authorization
After executing i am getting response like .[image: "Filed to authenticate token"]. Further, I have also used CSV file config for passing dynamic values.

I don't know what i am missing. Could anyone help me on this??

Comment: try using json responce extractor

Comment: Did you check (with something like a Debug Sampler or jp@gc - Dummy Sampler) if you extract the token correctly?

Answer (score 2):

First of all check your `${token}` variable value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination (see [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for details on how to do this).

It might be the case your regular expression extractor fails to fetch the token due to i.e. extra space.

Another assumption is that you need to add [Authentication Scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) identifier before the `${token}` like:

```
Authorization: Basic ${token}
```

or

```
Authorization: Bearer ${token}
```

Check out what is being sent by the real browser and JMeter, the requests must be identical (apart from dynamic values)